# Syntax enforcement for Java switch statment to check all known cases of Enum

Tags: java, enums

I wonder if modern Java lang syntax allows enforcement of check for all known Enum instances: no Enum element left without `case`.

Like for:

```
enum RGB { RED, GREEN, BLUE }
```

compiler should forbid:

```java
switch (rgb) {
case RED:
case BLUE:
// Oops we forgot GREEN!
}
```

I know `default: throw new IllegalStateException()` but that happens at runtime. I'm looking for compile time enforcement or weaker warning...

Comment: Errorprone has this case covered (pun intended): https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/MissingCasesInEnumSwitch

Comment: @FreeBird Seems errorprone won't report error if `default` is here. If some API was evolved I want to catch unhandled new `case`, I worry `default` disables warning...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Use the new switch-as-an-expression form (and I'm also throwing in the new arrow case labels but that's not pertinent to your question):

   ```
   int x = switch(rgb) {
       case RED -> 0xFF0000;
       case BLUE -> 0x0000FF;
       case GREEN -> 0x00FF00;
   };
   ```

   This will cause a compiler error if you forget a case.

   NB: These were properly introduced as preview in JDK13, and can be used without the `--enable-preview` switch starting with JDK14.

   If that's not what you are looking for, there is no compiler option, and in general java's compiler is not pluggable in this way (it's pluggable via the annotation processor system, which cannot generally look at code within methods, thus, cannot be used for this).
2. But what does exist is linting tools: Tools that scan your code and look for things. For example, most IDEs have them built in, and eclipse (which I'm familiar with - others may well have this too) has an option to generate a warning or error (whatever you prefer) for missed cases - this works on the 'old' switch statement as well. There are also standalone linting tools like sonarqube.

Comment: It's worth pointing out in which java version the new switch expressions are introduced (I believe it's java 14.)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html

Comment: edited answer to include references to the proper java versions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java 14, it is not clear if new syntax allows group of statements inside `case`. Nevertheless the proper solution seems to rely on some static analysis tool. Tnx!

Comment: @gavenkoa yes, the new syntax allows groups of statements. Just use `{ statement, statement, yield result; }`